# SELECT where not exists with another select statement

Tags: mysql

I have this code here:

```
select wms.product_code, WMS.barcode from(Select id,barcode, 
concat('0',barcode,checkdigit) as zc from outerb) as outerb 
join wms on outerb.zc = wms.barcode;
```

I need to select/view all values that are not matching based on the query above.

This is what I have already tried:

```
SELECT * FROM wms where not exists (select wms.product_code, WMS.barcode 
from(Select id,barcode, concat('0',barcode,checkdigit) as zc from outerb) as 
outerb 
join wms on outerb.zc = wms.barcode);
```

but this query, returns nothing. Also the `zc` table is a temporary table.

Using MySql Workbench

```
Table: outerb
Columns:
Id int(11) AI PK 
Product_code varchar(255) 
Brand varchar(255) 
Product_desc varchar(255) 
Size varchar(255) 
Barcode varchar(255) 
checkdigit varchar(255)

Table: wms
Columns:
Id int(11) AI PK 
Product_code varchar(255) 
Barcode varchar(255)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT * FROM wms where not exists 
    (select 1 from outerb where concat('0',barcode,checkdigit) = wms.barcode) 
and wms.barcode like '0123%'
```

Comment: @Eduards, you can check now

Comment: awesome! what does the `select 1` mean?

Comment: @Eduards, it's a constant value, you can select column name but as not exists only compare value so using constant makes the query more faster

Comment: it seems like `select 1` & `select *` work the same, returns the same amount of rows

Comment: @Eduards, its only matter in case of performance issue - nothing related with number of rows

Comment: This has nothing to do with speed. The syntax requires you select "something", while the `EXISTS` clause doesn't care which columns you select. So we select 1, null, or any other constant. To make this a habit has the advantage that this becomes readable and works with aggregation sub queries, too. While `select *` would work here and would be just as fast, it wouldn't work, if the sub query contained an aggregation. So we make this a constant instead in order to make `EXISTS` always look the same.

Comment: quick question... how would I show the values from wms.barcode that start with `'0123%'`? I have tried adding group by end of the code

Answer (score 1):

This gives you all WMS rows that have no match in OUTERB:

```
select *
from wms
where not exists
(
  select null
  from outerb o
  where concat('0', o.barcode, o.checkdigit) = wms.barcode
);
```

Or use `NOT IN`:

```
select *
from wms
where barcode not in (select concat('0', o.barcode, o.checkdigit) from outerb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM wms where wms.barcode not in (select concat('0',barcode,checkdigit) from outerb);
```

Comment: zc table is a temporary table not an existing table